# React Context not working - syntax issue?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, firebase-authentication, react-context

"login" is a function from React context.
This gives me an error:

```
   const handleLogin = async (data: LoginType) => {
      try {
         await login(auth, data.email, data.password);
         router.push("/Dashboard");
      } catch (error: any) {
         console.log(error.message);
      }
```

Login.tsx?cd12:54 Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(email),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field).  -- Full stack trace at bottom

But if I change it to the following, it works
(*signInWithEmailAndPassword* is from firebase/auth):

```
   const handleLogin = async (data: LoginType) => {
      try {
         await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.email, data.password);
         router.push("/Dashboard");
      } catch (error: any) {
         console.log(error.message);
      }
```

I did a console.log on the function parameters and they are identical in both cases.
This leads me to believe that I'm doing something syntactically wrong with the React context.
I looked at a few tutorials and SOF posts but am not sure how to fix my syntax.

---

I add the context "AuthContextProvider" in:

**_app.tsx**

```
import { AuthContextProvider } from "../config/AuthContext";

export default function App(props: AppProps & { colorScheme: ColorScheme }) {
   const { Component, pageProps } = props;
  };

   return (
      <AuthContextProvider>
         <Head>
            <title>Awesome App</title>
         </Head>
            <NotificationsProvider>
               <Component {...pageProps} />
            </NotificationsProvider>
      </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = async (appContext: AppContext) => {
  const appProps = await NextApp.getInitialProps(appContext);
  return { ...appProps };
};
```

This is the context:

**AuthContext.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
   onAuthStateChanged,
   createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
   signInWithEmailAndPassword,
   signOut,
 } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

interface UserType {
   email: string | null;
   uid: string | null;
}

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const useAuth = () => useContext<any>(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
   const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType>({ email: null, uid: null });
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

   useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
         if (user) {
            setUser({
               email: user.email,
               uid: user.uid,
         });
         } else {
            setUser({ email: null, uid: null });
         }
      });
      setLoading(false);

      return () => unsubscribe();
   }, []);

   const register = (email: string, password: string) => {
      return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
   };
 
   const login = (email: string, password: string) => {
      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
   };

   return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, register, login, logout }}>
         {loading ? null : children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
   );
};
```

This is my login component:

**Login.tsx**

```
import { auth } from "../../config/firebase";
import { useAuth } from '../../config/AuthContext';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

export function AuthenticationForm(props: PaperProps) {
   const handleLogin = async (data: LoginType) => {
      console.log(type);
      try {
         await login(auth, data.email, data.password);
         router.push("/Dashboard");
      } catch (error: any) {
         console.log(error.message);
      }

   return (
      ...
      <form onSubmit = { form.onSubmit(handleLogin) }>
      ...
   };
}
```

Stack trace:

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyCsRsNM7xW05sufMo7bwOWo-gnSLFlwILU 400
eval @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:933
await in eval (async)
_performFetchWithErrorHandling @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:943
_performApiRequest @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:914
_performSignInRequest @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:988
signInWithPassword @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:2885
_getIdTokenResponse @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:3007
_processCredentialSavingMfaContextIfNecessary @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:4575
_signInWithCredential @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:4716
signInWithCredential @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:4735
signInWithEmailAndPassword @ index-c6def6da.js?a9e1:5106
login @ AuthContext.tsx?c53f:44
eval @ Login.tsx?cd12:51
step @ tslib.es6.js?37cc:102
eval @ tslib.es6.js?37cc:83
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs?c03f:3
_next @ _async_to_generator.mjs?c03f:25
eval @ _async_to_generator.mjs?c03f:32
eval @ _async_to_generator.mjs?c03f:21
handleLogin @ Login.tsx?cd12:45
eval @ use-form.js?d6c0:156
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9097
eval @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:6430
Login.tsx?cd12:54 Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(email),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field).
```

Comment: you have exactly the error provided to you "Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(email),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field)" not the right value expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context `login` function:

```js
   const login = (email: string, password: string) => {
      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
   };
```

you are expecting an email and password only, but in your component, you are giving `auth` as first argument.

```js
   await login(auth, data.email, data.password);
```

Comment: thanks!
Just learned about React context, totally missed that part